# SQL Left Join (Multiple Join Condition)

Tags: sql-server-2005, validation, datetime, left-join, derived-table

I have two derived tables named Check Ins and Check Outs

**Check Ins**

```
CheckDate  CheckIn
---------- ---------
08/02/2011 10:10:03
08/02/2011 15:57:16
07/19/2011 13:58:52
07/19/2011 16:50:55
07/26/2011 15:11:24
06/21/2011 12:36:47
08/16/2011 14:49:36
08/09/2011 13:52:10
08/09/2011 16:54:51
08/23/2011 15:48:58
09/06/2011 15:23:00
09/13/2011 10:09:27
09/13/2011 10:40:14
09/13/2011 11:43:14
09/13/2011 11:59:32
09/13/2011 17:05:24
09/20/2011 11:03:42
09/20/2011 12:08:50
09/20/2011 15:21:06
09/20/2011 15:34:29
09/27/2011 11:34:06
10/04/2011 11:37:59
10/04/2011 15:24:04
10/04/2011 16:57:44
10/11/2011 18:19:33
```

**Check Outs**

```
CheckDate  CheckOut
---------- ---------
08/02/2011 13:29:40
08/02/2011 17:02:25
07/12/2011 17:06:06
07/19/2011 16:40:15
07/19/2011 17:07:35
07/26/2011 14:48:10
07/26/2011 17:27:08
05/31/2011 17:01:39
06/07/2011 17:04:29
06/14/2011 17:08:50
06/21/2011 17:03:46
06/28/2011 17:10:45
07/05/2011 17:02:48
08/16/2011 13:37:36
08/16/2011 17:06:34
08/09/2011 12:00:29
08/09/2011 13:29:36
08/09/2011 14:36:09
08/09/2011 17:00:38
08/23/2011 13:37:11
08/23/2011 17:01:37
09/06/2011 17:00:09
09/13/2011 10:11:50
09/13/2011 11:22:02
09/13/2011 11:47:35
09/13/2011 14:13:36
09/13/2011 14:14:25
09/13/2011 17:08:43
09/20/2011 09:54:55
09/20/2011 11:55:31
09/20/2011 11:55:36
09/20/2011 13:35:16
09/20/2011 15:26:02
09/20/2011 16:33:21
09/20/2011 17:07:52
09/27/2011 11:12:38
10/04/2011 13:26:31
10/04/2011 16:32:56
10/04/2011 17:02:35
10/11/2011 18:25:32
```

I want to pair the check ins with the check outs given the condition that both logs are on the same date and check out values cannot be earlier than check ins, so I have come up with this query

```
  SELECT A.ChkDt
      AS CheckDate,
         B.CheckIn,
         MIN(A.ChkTm)
      AS CheckOut
    FROM #tempAttLogs
      AS A LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT ChkDt
              AS CheckDate,
                 MIN(ChkTm)
              AS CheckIn
            FROM #tempAttLogs
           WHERE ChkTp = 'I'
        GROUP BY ChkDt) B
      ON A.ChkDt = B.CheckDate
   WHERE ChkTp = 'O' AND
         A.ChkTm > B.CheckIn
GROUP BY A.ChkDt, B.CheckIn
```

With a result set of

```
CheckDate  CheckIn   CheckOut
---------- --------- ---------
06/21/2011 12:36:47  17:03:46
07/19/2011 13:58:52  16:40:15
07/26/2011 15:11:24  17:27:08
08/02/2011 10:10:03  13:29:40
08/09/2011 13:52:10  14:36:09
08/16/2011 14:49:36  17:06:34
08/23/2011 15:48:58  17:01:37
09/06/2011 15:23:00  17:00:09
09/13/2011 10:09:27  10:11:50
09/20/2011 11:03:42  11:55:31
10/04/2011 11:37:59  13:26:31
10/11/2011 18:19:33  18:25:32
```

The thing is I also want to include the logs with no corresponding pairs. How can this be possible?

**EDIT**

My expected result set must include logs like this

```
CheckDate  CheckIn   CheckOut
---------- --------- ---------
05/23/2011 NULL      17:04:27
```

Comment: Trying to follow the logic: I would expect to be able to pair `in = 2011-02-08T15:57:16` with `out = 2011-02-08T17:02:25` but this does not appear in your resultset. Should it? It would be helpful if you posted your *expected* resultset.

Comment: Do you always check out and check in on the same date?  If the check out is close to midnight would the check in be the next day?

Comment: Using a datetime instead of separate dates and times might simplify your query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can move any predicate referencing the right hand table into the `ON` clause instead of the `WHERE` to avoid turning the `JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`

e.g.

```
ON A.ChkDt = B.CheckDate AND
         A.ChkTm > B.CheckIn
WHERE ChkTp = 'O'
```

Instead of

```
    ON A.ChkDt = B.CheckDate
   WHERE ChkTp = 'O' AND
         A.ChkTm > B.CheckIn
```

Comment: Never thought it would be that simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Include the null values in your WHERE clause Ex:

```
WHERE( ChkTp = 'O' AND
         A.ChkTm > B.CheckIn) OR B.CheckDate IS NULL
```

Comment: note that `JOIN ... ON A.ChkDt = B.CheckDate WHERE ... A.ChkTm > B.CheckIn` kinda cancel each other out in the OP question so you might want `A.ChkTm >= B.CheckIn` instead

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful (not tested) to solve your problem though it is at a slight tangent to your question.

```
select 
  Checkdate, CheckIn as CheckTime, 'I' as CheckAction
from CheckIns 

union all

select 
  Checkdate, CheckOut as CheckTime, 'O' as CheckAction
from CheckOuts
order by 1,2
```